# web application extracts uploaded tar files, is it vulnerable?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability

I have a python based web application running on a linux server,

**Is the following flow vulnerable?**

1. HTTP file upload (regular post from browser)
2. server validates max size before processes the file (before extraction)
3. file is processed - stored on temporary directory and named randomly (using a GUID as filename)
4. uploaded file (`tar.gz` file) is extracted using a new child process (tar working directory is also a temporary directory):

   ```
   tar xf <uploaded file path>
   ```
5. extracted files are being parsed (simple json files) and then deleted

Comment: Is the user in control of the filename? Can this be used to execute additional commands?

Comment: Check for directory traversal sequences (e.g. ../) in the file names before you extract. I've seen several such systems that fail to do this and let you put files in arbitrary directories. Place an executable files (PHP, JSP, etc.) in the web root and get a remote shell.

Comment: @Dogeatcatworld no, i'm naming the file with a GUID  generated on the server

Comment: @paj28, can a file inside a tar traverse outside of it's working directory? i'm extracting inside `/tmp/<random generated dir>/`

Comment: @JossefHarush - good, this closes the possibility of injecting parameters to tar, and possibly new commands if executed from a shell.

Comment: @JossefHarush - They certainly can. Your tar program/library may have protection - but many do not, or have had [flaws](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2001-1267/). The best thing to do is to test the library yourself.

Comment: What occurs when the user injects content into the file upload name using a proxy etc. Nulls unicode special strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you don't execute files contained in that tarball you're on the safe side of the fence.

As you seem to have realized, there is a potential threat (known as a zip bomb) which contains heavily compressed content which, when extracted without size checking, will use a huge amount of space on the disk.

// when you say max size you mean the size of the tar file or the size of the extracted files?

Comment: +1 for mentioning zip bombs. This makes checking the size before decompression more or less useless - you have to check during decompression or use `ulimit` to limit the file size and amount of usable memory.

Comment: max size before extraction, i'll check about `ulimit`. Thanks!